# AWS CloudFormation + Elastic Beanstalk error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am new to AWS CloudFormation and Elastic Beanstalk. I was able to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk successfully for a Java(Spring Boot) application but when I try to do it through CloudFormation, it's not working though I am running it through root account. it's a simple CloudFormation script, mostly taken from official page [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html):

> Cloudformation Error:
> The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyInstanceProfile, sampleEnvironment]. Rollback requested by user.

CloudFormation Json file:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "sampleApplication": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application"
      }
    },
    "sampleApplicationVersion": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion",
      "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": { "Ref": "sampleApplication" },
        "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version",
        "SourceBundle": {
          "S3Bucket": { "Fn::Join": [ "-", [ "bucket-elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" } ] ] },
          "S3Key": "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        }
      }
    },
    "sampleConfigurationTemplate": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
      "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": { "Ref": "sampleApplication" },
        "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template",
        "OptionSettings": [
          {
            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
            "OptionName": "MinSize",
            "Value": "2"
          },
          {
            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
            "OptionName": "MaxSize",
            "Value": "6"
          },
          {
            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
            "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
            "Value": "LoadBalanced"
          }
        ],
        "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.5 running Corretto 11"
      }
    },
    "sampleEnvironment": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
      "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": { "Ref": "sampleApplication" },
        "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment",
        "TemplateName": { "Ref": "sampleConfigurationTemplate" },
        "VersionLabel": { "Ref": "sampleApplicationVersion" }
      }
    },  
        "MyInstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Description": "Beanstalk EC2 role",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier"
                ]
            }
        },
        "MyInstanceProfile": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties": {
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "MyInstanceRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
  }
}
```

The full Events :

```
2021-10-06 09:27:05 UTC+0530    main-cf-sb2-2   ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   -
2021-10-06 09:27:04 UTC+0530    sampleApplication   DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:33 UTC+0530    MyInstanceRole  DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:33 UTC+0530    sampleApplication   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:33 UTC+0530    sampleConfigurationTemplate DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:33 UTC+0530    sampleApplicationVersion    DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:32 UTC+0530    sampleConfigurationTemplate DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:32 UTC+0530    sampleApplicationVersion    DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:32 UTC+0530    MyInstanceRole  DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:32 UTC+0530    MyInstanceProfile   DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:32 UTC+0530    sampleEnvironment   DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:26:31 UTC+0530    MyInstanceProfile   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:31 UTC+0530    sampleEnvironment   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:28 UTC+0530    main-cf-sb2-2   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyInstanceProfile, sampleEnvironment]. Rollback requested by user.
2021-10-06 09:26:27 UTC+0530    MyInstanceProfile   CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled
2021-10-06 09:26:27 UTC+0530    sampleEnvironment   CREATE_FAILED   Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state
2021-10-06 09:26:05 UTC+0530    MyInstanceProfile   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:26:05 UTC+0530    MyInstanceProfile   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:26:03 UTC+0530    MyInstanceRole  CREATE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:25:56 UTC+0530    sampleEnvironment   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:25:55 UTC+0530    sampleEnvironment   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:25:53 UTC+0530    sampleConfigurationTemplate CREATE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:25:53 UTC+0530    sampleConfigurationTemplate CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:25:53 UTC+0530    sampleApplicationVersion    CREATE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:25:53 UTC+0530    sampleApplicationVersion    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:25:52 UTC+0530    sampleApplicationVersion    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:25:52 UTC+0530    sampleConfigurationTemplate CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:25:50 UTC+0530    sampleApplication   CREATE_COMPLETE -
2021-10-06 09:25:50 UTC+0530    sampleApplication   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:25:50 UTC+0530    MyInstanceRole  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-06 09:25:50 UTC+0530    MyInstanceRole  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:25:50 UTC+0530    sampleApplication   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2021-10-06 09:25:46 UTC+0530    main-cf-sb2-2   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: where can I find the error? The only issue I see it in the "Events" tab in CloudFormation:
The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyInstanceProfile, sampleEnvironment]. Rollback requested by user.

Comment: This is not a full error. Scroll down the event log, reason should be detailed there.

Comment: I have updated the question with "All Events".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to resolve it. As the error was vague, I used another sample CloudFormation script on official page which deploys PHP application using Elastic Beanstalk.
This script had one difference:

```
 {
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
    "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
    "Value": {
        "Ref": "MyInstanceProfile"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others.
Full script:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "sampleApplication": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application"
            }
        },
        "sampleApplicationVersion": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion",
            "Properties": {
                "ApplicationName": {
                    "Ref": "sampleApplication"
                },
                "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version",
                "SourceBundle": {
                    "S3Bucket": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "elasticbeanstalk-samples-${AWS::Region}"
                    },
                    "S3Key": "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                }
            }
        },
        "sampleConfigurationTemplate": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
            "Properties": {
                "ApplicationName": {
                    "Ref": "sampleApplication"
                },
                "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template",
                "OptionSettings": [
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                        "OptionName": "MinSize",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                        "OptionName": "MaxSize",
                        "Value": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                        "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
                        "Value": "LoadBalanced"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                        "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "MyInstanceProfile"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.5 running Corretto 11"
            }
        },
        "sampleEnvironment": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
            "Properties": {
                "ApplicationName": {
                    "Ref": "sampleApplication"
                },
                "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment",
                "TemplateName": {
                    "Ref": "sampleConfigurationTemplate"
                },
                "VersionLabel": {
                    "Ref": "sampleApplicationVersion"
                }
            }
        },
        "MyInstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Description": "Beanstalk EC2 role",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier"
                ]
            }
        },
        "MyInstanceProfile": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties": {
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "MyInstanceRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```